# Handling errors inside Sinatra's configuration block

Tags: ruby, error-handling, sinatra

What's an idiomatic way to handle errors inside Sinatra's configuration blocks?

For example, if an app fails to connect to the database inside the config, I would like to either communicate the error (`halt`) or show some specific error page (`redirect`)... But such methods aren't available in `configure` blocks.

```ruby
configure do
    begin
        db = Sequel.connect ENV['HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_URL'] 
        db.test_connection
    rescue
        # Neither of these are available at `configure` block level
        halt 503, "Unavailable to connect to DB."
        redirect ("/custom-error-page")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `configure` block runs at server startup, so any client-faced operation such as `halt` or `redirect` makes no sense, because there is actually no user when that code runs.

I would just let the error bubble up and thus refuse to start the server when such things happen since it is very likely, that your application will be inherently broken when the configuration fails.

Comment: How far would you let it bubble up? Where do you catch the error to refuse server start-up?

Comment: I mean don't catch it at all.

Comment: I would like to communicate the error message (or messages) in a meaningful way, instead of a generic "Internal Network Error" when the server crashes.

Comment: Again, who will you display the error to? At the time when the exception happens, there is no user.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Let's assume I'm not doing something as singular as connecting to the DB, but something that can wrong more often; for example, loading data from a remote API. I feel like you're presuming that the app can only have one instance running; whereas I have multiple instances on a cloud service. Just because one thread loads data at some point in time, there's no guarantee that the other instances, when they initialize, will be able to connect to the data source, and the user is left wondering.

Comment: I see. What I meant is: will the instance even start when the error occurs? If not, then I don't see the problem.